# Taskbar partially missing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and I have a dual monitor set up. In the past, both screens shows the same desktop/taskbar and I can access the taskbar from either screen. Just recently I noticed large pieces of the taskbar on my secondary monitor are missing? The issue isn't necessarily that my taskbar isn't there, but more that it's only showing parts of it. If I hover my mouse over where the taskbar would be, I can still click and access different programs I have pinned to my taskbar.
Has this happened before to anyone and were you able to fix it?

Here's a screenshot of my primary monitor:
[image]

and here's a screenshot of my secondary monitor:[image]

you can see the second one only shows the Task View button and even then not the entire thing.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a screenshot of the issue? It sounds like a non-standard problem.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the taskbar, click properties.
There will be a section on the bottom third called 'Multiple displays'

Here you can customize how much of the taskbar appears on the secondary display.

The Default is:
Show taskbar on all displays (checked)

Show Buttons on:
All Taskbars

Buttons on other taskbars:
Always combine, show labels.

Comment: I checked this out and my task bar properties are set to default. I have "show taskbar on all displays" checked and show buttons set to "all taskbars". However my "buttons on other taskbars" option is set to "always combine, hide labels" and I don't have the option to "always combine, show labels". I don't think that's related to the issue at hand though...

Comment: I apologize, I don't have enough rep to comment on questions. Are you running software to stretch a wallpaper across two displays? Also, which graphics driver are you using? (Intel, AMD, nVidia?)

Comment: No worries, and no I don't believe my wallpaper is stretched. Both monitors have the same picture but it's not stretched between them. Also I believe my graphics driver is nVidia if that helps.

Comment: Is there any chance you have tried [this?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/fix-windows-10-taskbar-not-working-fix-build-10074/6b13e8b6-b30b-4e80-aa7c-a4a3939195ea?auth=1) And worst case, trying to replicate your setup on a new user?

Comment: I haven't heard from you, I hope you got this resolved. Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem for over a year and the only solution I've found so far is:

- opening the Task Manager (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC)</kbd>,
- find and select Windows Explorer,
- then click Restart.

This will get your taskbar buttons back (but will also close all opened Explorers).

A better solution...

Toggle the Auto hide of the Taskbar in the Taskbar Settings

Comment: Just found a better solution ;)

Comment: Toggle the Auto hide of the Taskbar in the Taskbar Settings

Comment: You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1516585/edit) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get my taskbar back I had to move taskbar to another position and then back.  The main display loses its taskbar and it becomes an outline.  I need background processes which is only on main display.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this having a similar problem. Mine was just showing the frame. The suggestion from https://superuser.com/users/549482/mikeymop put me in the right window to fix it for myself.

**The "Taskbar location on screen," in Taskbar settings, had changed to custom and changing it back to right (for right side taskbar) made it show properly again.**

[image: Screen capture of taskbar location combo box in taskbar settings - Show badges on taskbar buttons - off - taskbar location on screen - right - combine taskbar buttons]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and what worked for me was rescaling the specific display that had a missing taskbar to 125%, waiting for the taskbar to render, and rescaling back to 100%.

Answer (score -1):

This could be fixed by updating the Driver.

You can open Device Manager -> Display Adapter, double click on any of the adapter you can see -> go into Driver tag -> choose “Update driver”.

Then you can select “Search automatically for updated driver software”.

This works great for me, hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

For me: **simply restarting actually resolved it**.

This may seem like a trivial answer but I spent a couple hours trying to resolve this issue where the taskbar was being cut in half at the bottom of the screen. It wasn't a resolution or driver issue. It was simply a temporary glitch on first connection.